# net.TCPConn allowing Write after FIN packet

Tags: tcp, go

I'm trying to write unit tests for some server-side code, but I'm having trouble being deterministic with my shutdown test cases. It seems a loopback TCP connection isn't correctly handling a clean shutdown. I've reprod this in a sample app which does the following in lockstep:

1. Create a client & server connection.
2. Verify connectivity by sending a message successfully from client to server.
3. Use channels to tell the server to call conn.Close() and wait until that call has completed.
4. (Try to) verify the connection is cleanly broken by calling Write on the client connection again.

Step 4 succeeds without error. I've tried using a json.Encoder and a bare call to TCPConn.Write. I checked the traffic with WireShark. The server sent a FIN packet, but the client never does (even with a 1s sleep) The server even sent a RST packet in response to (4) and the client conn.Write still returned nil for its error.

This seems totally bonkers. Am I missing something here? Currently running Go v1.2.1/Darwin

**Edit: Obligatory repro**

```
package main

import (
  "bufio"
  "fmt"
  "net"
)

var (
  loopback = make(chan string)
  shouldClose = make(chan struct{})
  didClose = make(chan struct{})
)

func serve(listener *net.TCPListener) {
  conn, err := listener.Accept()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  s := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
  if !s.Scan() {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("Failed to scan for line: ", s.Err()))
  }

  loopback <- s.Text() + "\n"

  <-shouldClose
  conn.Close()
  close(didClose)

  if s.Scan() {
    panic("Expected error reading from a socket closed on this side")
  }
}

func main() {
  listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", &net.TCPAddr{})
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  go serve(listener)

  conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", listener.Addr().String())
  if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("Dialer got error ", err))
  }

  oracle := "Mic check\n"
  if _, err = conn.Write([]byte(oracle)); err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprint("Dialer failed to write oracle: ", err))
  }

  test := <-loopback
  if test != oracle {
    panic("Server did not receive the value sent by the client")
  }

  close(shouldClose)
  <-didClose

  // For giggles, I can also add a <-time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
  if _, err = conn.Write([]byte("This should fail after active disconnect")); err == nil {
    panic("Sender 'successfully' wrote to a closed socket")
  }
}
```

Comment: A TCP connection is not closed after receiving a FIN. That side can then chose to ACK the FIN, and enter a half-closed state where it could potentially send more data. Normally though, the side receiving the FIN, send a ACK and a FIN of its own to fully close down the connection.

Answer (score 4):

This is how an active close of a TCP connection works. When the client detects that the server has closed, it is then expected to close its half of the connection.

In your case, instead of closing the client you're sending more data. This causes the server to send an RST packet to force the connection closed since the message received isn't valid.

If you're still unsure, here's and equivalent python client+server which displays the same behavior.  (I find using python helpful, since it closely follows the underlying BSD socket API, without using C)

Server:

```
import socket, time

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9999))
server.listen(1)
sock, addr = server.accept()
msg = sock.recv(1024)
print msg
print "closing"
sock.close()
time.sleep(3)
print "done"
```

Client:

```
import socket, time

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9999))
sock.send("test\n")
time.sleep(1)
print "sending again!"
sock.send("no error here")
time.sleep(1)
print "sending one last time"
sock.send("broken pipe this time")
```

To properly detect a remote close on the connection, you should do  `Read()`, and look for an `io.EOF` error in return.

```
// we technically need to try and read at least one byte, 
// or we will get an EOF even if the connection isn't closed.
buff := make([]byte, 1)
    if _, err := conn.Read(buff); err != io.EOF {
    panic("connection not closed")
}
```

Comment: My concern was that the Go API covers up this information. There's no way to ask whether the connection was closed, so I would expect the library to honor the FIN. This is more of a Go question than a "how does TCP work" question.

Comment: @ThomasBouldin: go isn't covering anything up, it's exposing the details of the underlying TCP connection (or I guess more soundly, the BSD socket API). The way to detect a remote close on a TCP connection is to do a `recv`, and read 0 bytes, and Go exposes that by returning an EOF error after a Read (along with 0 bytes read).

Comment: So Go's method of checking for/acknowledging a FIN is to read 0B?

Comment: @ThomasBouldin: yes, because that is how you know if a connection closed (hidden or "magical" behavior is very much against the design of the language). Technically though, in Go you should be checking for `io.EOF`, since you're probably operating on a `net.Conn` or an `io.Reader`, and may not be aware of that actual underlying transport.

Comment: Actually, this isn't of any help. I added a conn.Read(nil) before and after the server closed the socket and both returned io.EOF. io.EOF is also used to say there aren't buffered bytes ready to read, so it seems indistinguishable from having received a FIN. This means I cannot use this technique to know when I'm expected to close the write end of the client.

Comment: @ThomasBouldin: sorry, my bad. Using a nil buffer inadvertently triggers the `EOF`, because the only indicator that EOF is reached is the condition of "0 bytes read". If you put a proper byte-slice in there, it will block as expected before the connection closes.

Comment: @ThomasBouldin read() on a TCP connection returning 0 to indicate the peer did a graceful close (i.e. you received a FIN) is how the socket API is implemented in virtually any operating system (and the programming languages available on those operating system either expose that directly, or return something similar to "EOF").