# Why can I successfully post a message to the closed server?

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

```
func main() {
    server := "localhost:8989"
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", server)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fatal error: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fatal error: %s", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("connect success")
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        j, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("conn.Write err: %v\n", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("time[%v] conn.Write len: %v\n", i+1, j)
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

I post 10 messages to tcp server with the demo. And I get this:

```
    connect success
time[1] conn.Write len: 5
time[2] conn.Write len: 5
time[3] conn.Write len: 5
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
conn.Write err: write tcp 127.0.0.1:52462->127.0.0.1:8989: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

I closed the server before the third message. But the third message post successfully. The `conn.Write err` get nil. I can't understand. Who can tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: The server was faster than you.

Comment: Without more details on the server, we can't tell you exactly. Most probably cause is that the server didn't close exactly at the time you think it did, and that the third write was indeed successful. If you have access to the server code, you could log output to check that out.

Comment: @Elwinar, you can reproduce it with this simple server: https://play.golang.org/p/vcsvAOCCf_a. I suspect there's some buffering going on, but I find it surprising nonetheless. Increasing the message size to >64k doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is how TCP works. You can’t detect a remote close by sending packets, until the remote machine responds with an RST.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879000/net-tcpconn-allowing-write-after-fin-packet/23879617#23879617 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830549/golang-write-net-conn-without-returning-error-but-the-other-side-of-the-socket-c/28835339#28835339

Comment: @JimB so, only if I read remote can I detect it close. Right? Forgive my pool english.

Comment: @QinglongLi: yes, that is correct. You detect a remote close by reading the connection.